# Proving the derived set $E'$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

I was reading the proof in Rudin, but it uses the metric. Is this not true if $X$ is a general topological space and $E' \subset X$ (especially if it is not Hausdorff $T_1$)?

I can't come up with a counterexample. To be specific, it's difficult for me to pass from one neighbourhood to the other without using a metric.

Note that $E'$ is the set of all limit points.

Comment: Just to make sure: $E'$ is the set of limit points of $E$?

Comment: @DanielFischer, yes. Whoops.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without any separation axioms, the set of limit points of a set need not be closed. Consider a two-element set, $X = \{a,b\}$, with the trivial topology. Let $E = \{a\}$. Then $E' = \{b\}$ is not closed.

If we assume $T_1$, the set of limit points is closed. If $E' = \varnothing$, there's nothing to show, so let us suppose $E'\neq\varnothing$, and let $x \in \overline{E'}$. Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$. Then $U\cap E' \neq\varnothing$. Let $y\in U\cap E'$. If $y = x$, we're done. Otherwise, $U\setminus \{x\}$ is an open neighbourhood of $y$, and thus $(U\setminus\{x,y\}) \cap E \neq \varnothing$, since $y \in E'$. But that implies $(U\setminus \{x\}) \cap E \neq \varnothing$, and since $U$ was arbitrary, $x\in E'$.

Comment: Oh my gosh, the example is so simple.

Comment: Why isn't $a \in E'$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Because $(X\setminus \{a\})\cap E = \varnothing$. A limit point of $E$ is a point $x$ such that every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point of $E$ _different from_ $x$.

Comment: @DanielFischer of course... that was bothering me, thank you

Comment: @DanielFischer, I think you mean to let $x \in cl(E' - \{x \})$

Comment: @sidht That doesn't matter, it's the same set. $$(U\setminus \{x\})\cap E' = (U\cap [X\setminus \{x\}]) \cap E' = U \cap ([X\setminus \{x\}] \cap E') = U \cap (E'\setminus \{x\}).$$ I prefer to work with punctured neighbourhoods.

Comment: @sidht No. The claim is that $E'$ is closed, that is $E' = \overline{E'}$, not that every $x\in E'$ is a limit point of $E'$. The latter does not even hold in metric spaces, consider $E = \{2^{-n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \subset \mathbb{R}$. Then $E' = \{0\}$.

Comment: I see, I came up with the following proof. I'll just go straight to the punchline of the triangle inequality. $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z) < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon.$