# Show that if $X$ is a top space and A subset of X then X is $T_1$-space iff $A'$ is closed

Tags: general-topology

Show that if $X$ is a top space and $A$ subset of $X$ , then $X$ is $T_1$-space iff $A'$ is closed.

$T_1$

If for each pair of distinct points a,b,∃open sets $U,V$ such that  $ a∈U,b∉U,a∉V,b∈V$.
.

Comment: [No.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954578/x-tau-needs-to-be-t-1-in-order-to-guarantee-that-a-is-closed)

Comment: No. Consider  a space $X$ with more than one point, and the coarse topology.