# Double derived set in $T_0$ spaces

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

Let $A$ be a subset of a topological space $X$. I am interested in establishing under which conditions the following inclusion holds: $A'' \subseteq A'.$

This is certainly false in general: consider the two point space $X=\{x, y\}$ with the indiscrete topology. Then $\{x\}'=\{y\}$ and $\{y\}'=\{x\}$.

On the other hand this is true for $T_1$ spaces. For, if $x \in A''$ any neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ contains a point $y\in A', y\ne x$; then if $V_y$ is a neighborhood of $y$ which does not contain $x$, $V_y \cap U_x$ is a neighborhood of $y$ and hence contains a point $z \in A, z\ne x, z \in U_x$.

Question is: is $T_0$ axiom enough for the inclusion to hold true? I can't prove this nor find a counterexample.

Comment: Isn't $\{x\}^\prime = \{x,y\}$, since both points are topologically indistinguishable?

Comment: $x \notin \{x\}'$ since the only non empty nbdh of $x$ is $\{x, y\}$, but $\{x, y\} \cap \{x\} = \{x\}$. Then it is not true that every nbdh of $x$ intersects $\{x\}$ (the given set) in a point different from $x$; hence $x\notin \{x\}'$.

Comment: Oh, then I had a completely wrong definition of limit point and derived set… thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A'' \subseteq A'$ happens precisely when derived sets are closed.

[This recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/955251/4280) examimes
the question quite thoroughly, and gives a $T_0$ counterexample (Sierpinski's space) as well. It's somewhere between $T_0$ and $T_1$ in nature.