# Complement of derived set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is the complement of derived set of a set E equal to the set of all isolated points of E?
Further my actual ques is to prove that derived set of E is closed. So i tried this way .
Complement of derived set = union of interior points of E complement and isolated points of E.
Now set of interior points of E complement is open.
Set of isolated point is open. And Union if open sets is open.
So union of interior points of E complement and isolated points of E is open. Then derived set of E is closed. 
Is this approach ok? I have almost no knowledge about these.

Answer (score 0):

For $E \subseteq X$, $x \notin E'$ iff $x \in E$ and $x$ is an isolated point of $E$, or $x \notin E$ and $x$ has an open neighbourhood that misses $E$, which is indeed an interior point of $E^\complement$. (E.g. $2$ is not a limit point of $[0,1]$ (usual topology on the reals).)

The interior of $E^\complement$ is an open set, but the isolated points of $E$ need not be open (in $X$), so this way of trying to show $E'$ is closed needs more work.

To show $E'$ is a closed set, we do need to assume that $X$ is a $T_1$ space (or restrict ourselves to spaces where this is automatic, like metric or ordered spaces). In general, counterexamples exist, a particularly boring one being the indiscrete topology on $\{0,1\}$ and $E=\{0\}$ where $E'=\{1\}$ is not closed. For a correct proof for $T_1$ spaces, look at [Daniel's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/940849/4280), e.g. There are more to be found at this site.